# add php code to display sku in before error message

Tags: php, extensions, sku

we are using an extension to import the products.

This is the code we are using to display some error message.

we are using this file to display error message :

```
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist', $attributeCode);
```

Before the error message , i want to display the sku .
i guesss usually we need to display following code to display sku :

```
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku();
```

i want to merge the above 2 lines of code, so that i want to display as

"sku : some error message"

Comment: The class you've uploaded is pretty big. Also, I'm pretty sure this is a paid extensions so you shouldn't be posting their code online. Please contact the module builder for support

Comment: okay, but they are not replying.....

Comment: The SKU should be available by using `$data['sku']` in this case. Please remove the link to the paid module's code.

Comment: @SanderMangel i removed the code

Comment: @TylerV. i removed the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far i understand you want to show message like that

```
if(trim($value) == '') {
                    $errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "sku"',$value);
                }else { 
                        $sku=trim($value);
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('%s: Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist', $sku, $attributeCode);

                            $data[$code] = $value;
                    }
```

Comment: i will try this.....

Comment: `__('%s: Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist', $sku, $attributeCode)` seems the right way to me

Comment: please check the line number 1102 and 1103 here : http://pastebin.com/zJBzBXEB, because still i am not getting sku

Comment: go 404 error can paste line here?

Comment: no error i am getting but sku is not displaying

Comment: i can get access the to this code can you give me code here which line you mentions?

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: replace else and check you will get the sku?

Comment: i changed like this : if($validationRequiredFlag)
     else { 
                        $sku=trim($value);
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('%s: Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist', $sku, $attributeCode);

                            $data[$code] = $value;
                    }   but still not working

Comment: update the answer follow it

Comment: i replaced following lines by your code :

if($validationRequiredFlag)
 

$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist',$attributeCode);

but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30200/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-2-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 1):

Should be simple enough as:

```
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($existProductId)->getSku();
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('%s: Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist', $sku, $attributeCode);
```

This will also support the multi-locale translation.

Comment: please check the line number 1102 and 1103 here : http://pastebin.com/zJBzBXEB, because still i am not getting sku

Comment: check my updated code.

Comment: no, still sku is not displaying

Comment: did you check your error logs?

Comment: there is no errors related to this extension